# Setting location of a button in a jframe not working

Tags: java, swing

I have a method that is just adding a button to a JPanel. I have a problem however, where there are some properties of this button that I cannot modify.

`setBackground` and `setLocation` method don't affect the button at all.  I'm trying to move the button to the bottom of the `JPannel` but nothing seems to happen when I try setting the horizontal alignment or location.

```java
    public static void initButtons() {
        JButton purchaseButton = new JButton();
        purchaseButton.setText("Proceed to Checkout");
        purchaseButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
        purchaseButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/alecr/eclipse-workspace/MakingPurchases/src/shopping_cart_sprite.png"));
// set location method not working
        purchaseButton.setLocation(25, 600);

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(); 
        firstPanel.setBounds(25, 40, 300, 700);
        firstPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(90,90,100));
        firstPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(3.0f), new Color(70,70,80)));
        frame.add(firstPanel);

        firstPanel.add(purchaseButton);
    }
```

Comment: Set a LayoutManager for your panel and add the button with the correct constraints.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setLocation` and `setBounds` for each component, you should [use a proper LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and let it do the work for you. Having hard coded sizes and locations will not allow your application be scalable for different screen sizes and your `JFrame` will not be able to be resizable, which is not so user-friendly.

However, if you insist of using absolute-hard coded  values  (coordinates and dimensions) you must remove the layout manager from the container (a `JPanel` [uses FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) by default), because like I mentioned, it takes care of such things. In order to do that:

`JPanel panel = new JPanel(null); //null layout manager allows absolute values`

Comment: I've set the layout manager to `null`, which works for setting the bounds now.  I'd also like to switch the colour.  Is there a way this could be done as the method `purchaseButton.setBackground(Color.blue);` didn't work.

Comment: @Hydra I'm afraid, this is a question for another topic. But before you ask, do some research. Doesn't sound a bit common to you? Maybe it has already an answer out there?